# Passing values to a function in C

Tags: c, function, berkeley-db

I am new to C and working on it since two months. I have a structure shown below:

```
struct profile_t
{
    unsigned char length;
    unsigned char type;
    unsigned char *data;
};

typedef struct profile_datagram_t
{
    unsigned char *src;
    unsigned char *dst;
    unsigned char ver;
    unsigned char n;
    struct profile_t profiles[MAXPROFILES];
} header;

header outObj;
```

Now the values inside the elements of the structure are read as `outObj.src[i]`, `outObj.dst[i]`, and `outObj.profiles[i].type`.

Now I want to call a function and pass the values read by me to a function which is actually a Berkeley DB.

```
void main()
{
    struct pearson_record {
        unsigned char src[6];
        unsigned char dst[6];
        unsigned char type;
    };

    DB *dbp;
    int ret;

    if ((ret = db_create(&dbp, dbenv, 0)) !=0)
        handle_error(ret);

    if ((ret = dbp->open(dbp, NULL, "pearson.db", NULL, DB_BTREE, DB_CREATE, 0600)) !=0)
        handle_error(ret);

    const DBT *pkey;
    const DBT *pdata;

    struct pearson_record p;
    DBT data, key;

    memset(&key, 0, sizeof(DBT));
    memset(&data, 0, sizeof(DBT));

    memset(&s, 0, sizeof(struct pearson_record));
```

Now the above code is written by looking at a example from the DB reference guide. but i don't understand what is `const DBT`. Also they have added the value inside structure using `memcopy` which I know is the right way, but now I want to `memcopy` the values passed which are mentioned above and store them in the structure `pearson_record`. How should I go with this?? Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please post the complete code. You mention "they memcopy" (which I assume you refer to memcpy), but all I see is a bunch of memset(*,0). Hope you're not confusing them.

Also "they have added the value inside structure using memcopy which I know is the right way" is not entirely true. It's not necessarily wrong, BUT... char* is basically interpreted as a C string. that is an array of bytes which represent characters which MUST be null terminated (that is the last character must be 0, equivalent to '\0'). The proper way to copy strings is using strcpy() (or strcpy_s on windows), the difference is memcpy is faster and used in other situations (such as pointers\buffer management).

unsigned char* is not so used (at least I never saw it till now). As a note read about char, unsigned char, signed char, char[] and char* (not that it changes your code in any way, but just to make sure you understand the differences).

As for copying data, I assume you mean src, dst and type from pearson_record to header, correct ? If so, for the sake of simplicity I wanted to suggest memcpy but you say that each element is accessed as [i]. Does that mean header.src is an array of more than one pearson_record.src or does  header.src[i] correspond to pearson_record.src[i] ? This is slightly unclear to me.

There is a difference between char* src and char* *src.